# Stuck trying to optimize complex GLSL fragment shader

Tags: opengl, optimization, glsl, lighting

So first off, let me say that while the code works perfectly well from a visual point of view, it runs into very steep performance issues that get progressively worse as you add more lights. In its current form it's good as a proof of concept, or a tech demo, but is otherwise unusable.

Long story short, I'm writing a RimWorld-style game with real-time top-down 2D lighting. The way I implemented rendering is with a 3 layered technique as follows:

First I render occlusions to a single-channel `R8` occlusion texture mapped to a framebuffer. This part is lightning fast and doesn't slow down with more lights, so it's not part of the problem:

[image]

Then I invoke my lighting shader by drawing a huge rectangle over my lightmap texture mapped to another framebuffer. The light data is stored in an array in an UBO and it uses the occlusion mapping in its calculations. This is where the slowdown happens:

[image]

And lastly, the lightmap texture is multiplied and added to the regular world renderer, this also isn't affected by the number of lights, so it's not part of the problem:

[image]

The problem is thus in the lightmap shader. [The first iteration](https://github.com/myblindy/tweey/blob/d93ca276840c31253aba1b119790d8308f745388/tweey/Data/Shaders/lightmap.frag) had many branches which froze my graphics driver right away when I first tried it, but after removing most of them I get a solid 144 fps at 1440p with 3 lights, and ~58 fps at 1440p with 20 lights. An improvement, but it scales very poorly. The shader code is as follows, with additional annotations:

```
#version 460 core

// per-light data
struct Light
{
    vec4 location;
    vec4 rangeAndstartColor;
};
const int MaxLightsCount = 16;    // I've also tried 8 and 32, there was no real difference

layout(std140) uniform ubo_lights
{
    Light lights[MaxLightsCount];
};

uniform sampler2D occlusionSampler;  // the occlusion texture sampler

in vec2 fs_tex0;                     // the uv position in the large rectangle
in vec2 fs_window_size;              // the window size to transform world coords to view coords and back

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    vec3 resultColor = vec3(0.0);
    const vec2 size = fs_window_size;
    const vec2 pos = (size - vec2(1.0)) * fs_tex0;

    // process every light individually and add the resulting colors together
    // this should be branchless, is there any way to check?
    for(int idx = 0; idx < MaxLightsCount; ++idx)
    {
        const float range = lights[idx].rangeAndstartColor.x;
        const vec2 lightPosition = lights[idx].location.xy;
        const float dist = length(lightPosition - pos);    // distance from current fragment to current light

        // early abort, the next part is expensive
        // this branch HAS to be important, right? otherwise it will check crazy long lines against occlusions
        if(dist > range)
            continue;

        const vec3 startColor = lights[idx].rangeAndstartColor.yzw;

        // walk between pos and lightPosition to find occlusions
        // standard line DDA algorithm
        vec2 tempPos = pos;
        int lineSteps = int(ceil(abs(lightPosition.x - pos.x) > abs(lightPosition.y - pos.y) ? abs(lightPosition.x - pos.x) : abs(lightPosition.y - pos.y)));
        const vec2 lineInc = (lightPosition - pos) / lineSteps;

        // can I get rid of this loop somehow? I need to check each position between 
        // my fragment and the light position for occlusions, and this is the best I 
        // came up with
        float lightStrength = 1.0;
        while(lineSteps --> 0)
        {
            const vec2 nextPos = tempPos + lineInc;
            const vec2 occlusionSamplerUV = tempPos / size;
            lightStrength *= 1.0 - texture(occlusionSampler, vec2(occlusionSamplerUV.x, 1 - occlusionSamplerUV.y)).x;

            tempPos = nextPos;
        }

        // the contribution of this light to the fragment color is based on 
        // its square distance from the light, and the occlusions between them
        // implemented as multiplications
        const float strength = max(0, range - dist) / range * lightStrength;
        resultColor += startColor * strength * strength;
    }

    color = vec4(resultColor, 1.0);
}
```

I call this shader as many times as I need, since the results are additive. It works with large batches of lights or one by one. Performance-wise, I didn't notice any real change trying different batch numbers, which is perhaps a bit odd.

So my question is, is there a better way to look up for any (boolean) occlusions between my fragment position and light position in the occlusion texture, without iterating through every pixel by hand? Could render buffers perhaps help here (from what I've read they're for reading data back to system memory, I need it in another shader though)?

And perhaps, is there a better algorithm for what I'm doing here?

Comment: "*Long story short, I'm writing a RimWorld-style game with real-time top-down 2D lighting.*" For those who don't know what "RimWorld" is or don't know how its "top-down 2D lighting" works, this does not in fact make the long story short.

Comment: One minor optimization is to pre-compute `1/size` so to use a multiplication instead (AFAIK the compiler cannot do that because the IEEE-754 standard needs to be fulfilled). For the loop, I think the problem is not much the loops but the random-like memory access to the texture. Maybe a better strategy is to iterated over blocks of fragments since shadows are only a fraction of the overall space. That being said, IDK if this is possible with fragment shaders. At least certainly not in one pass.

Comment: @NicolBolas, perhaps not, but I did include a lot of images

Comment: Maybe you need a way to not check every light for each pixel of your image during the 2 passes. Something close to a quadtree based on your `range` parameter but on the gpu... You can use SSBO for dynamic buffer with varying size.

Comment: I don't think the number of lights checked is the problem, because I'm always checking all of them (the branch to check only the amount of lights necessary was killing performance), and frame rate only drops when a light is actually in range of the fragment (ie passes the first `if`). It's the DDA algorithm and the repeated texture lookups that are the big problem, but I'm having difficulty imagining a different way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple routes for optimization:

1. Exact: apply a [distance transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) on the occlusion map: this will give you the distance to the nearest occluder at each pixel. After that you can safely step by that distance within the loop, instead of doing baby steps. This will drastically reduce the number of steps in open regions.

   There is a very simple CPU-side algorithm to compute a DT, and it may suit you if your occluders are static. If your scene changes every frame, however, you'll need to search the literature for GPU side algorithms, which seem to be more complicated.
2. Inexact: resort to soft shadows -- it might be a compromise you are willing to make, and even seen as an artistic choice. If you are OK with that, you can create a mipmap from your occlusion map, and then progressively increase the step and sample lower levels as you go farther from the point you are shading.

   You can go further and build an emitters map (into the same 4-channel map as the occlusion). Then your entire shading pass will be independent of the number of lights. This is an equivalent of voxel cone tracing GI applied to 2D.

Comment: #1 is interesting. The light map changes every frame (actors move around), but the occlusion map is relatively static (though it does move while scrolling). Hm. I'll think about it some more. #2 however seems like it's more than just inexact, it sounds like it would leak light through walls (or at least do many times more computations in tight quarters, decreasing the mipmap level over and over until you're back to the original value).

Comment: @Blindy if thin walls are common, there is a way to reduce light leaks by employing directional occlusion and filtering. Not sure what you mean by "decreasing the mipmap level over and over", that's not how cone tracing works -- you only ever go up the mipmap levels. You may want to read through the [nvidia paper](https://research.nvidia.com/publication/2011-09_interactive-indirect-illumination-using-voxel-cone-tracing). The coolest part of #2 is that it's independent of the number of lights.